# ClamTk not showing scan results and history

Tags: logging, clamav, clamtk

Whenever I use ClamTk to scan folders, it won't show **list of infected files** after scanning is completed. What it shows is just a total number of scanned files and number of infected files.

How can I see which files are infected in ClamTk?

I also headed to History section and it's empty there.
And /home/user/.clamtk/history folder is empty.

There is no options to set about logging and history in ClamTk GUI.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 if that means anything.
Thanks!

Comment: How are you running `clamtk`?  Are you running it as `sudo clamtk` or just `clamtk`?

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: @Terrance I usually run it from Launcher, so I guess it was without sudo. Then I just tried with sudo, after the scan finished the terminal gave me this: https://pastebin.com/raw/hbhZxZwi. However the history is still empty.

Comment: @George According to GUI, it's ClamTk 5.20.

Comment: @V412270 mine's the same and it shows all that perhaps a re-install might shake things up

Comment: I encountered the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

Solved by launching clamtk at terminal with

```
env LC_TIME=C clamtk
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by changing `clamTk` launcher and `thunar` custom action to this command string:

```
env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 clamtk %F
```

So, if you edit `clamtk.desktop` file you could change the string:

```
Exec=clamtk %F
```

to

```
Exec=env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 clamtk %F
```

This works fine for me.
The scanning process shows a result window and the `History` section contains the previous scan logs.